# Select single found result with MATCH AGAINST

Tags: php, mysql, match, against

I am trying to get a single result from a table row

I'm using this query

```
"SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE MATCH(nombre, mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4, mat5, mat6, mat7) 
AGAINST ('$busqueda' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY nombre";
```

This obviously selects all the fields of the row if `$busqueda` is found in any of the fields.

Is there a way to select only the field where the search term is found?

Comment: $busqueda = "'"; <-- causes error, might dump query. If it does, I have the table name. Then, next time around: $busqueda = "'); drop table [table name]; --"; // I assume you are scrubbing for SQL injections like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MATCH(nombre, mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4, mat5, mat6, mat7)` acts as a single index field, so when some text matches against it, it does not have a facility to tell you which bit.

You can still match against the full spread for speed of matching like this, and use individual `MATCH()` calls against each field in the the field list (after the `SELECT` in place of `*`) checking the relevance for a certain level in order to detect which field was matching.

```
SELECT
   IF(MATCH(nombre) AGAINST ('search phrase' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0.9, nombre, NULL) AS nombre,
   IF(MATCH(mat1) AGAINST ('search phrase' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0.9, mat1, NULL) AS mat1
   /* etc */
FROM myTable
WHERE MATCH(nombre, mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4, mat5, mat6, mat7) 
      AGAINST ('search phrase' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY nombre
```

NULLs will be returned for fields that do not match, note that you may well want `FULLTEXT` indexes on the individual fields too.  It is not an absolute requirement if using `BOOLEAN MODE` if I remember correctly.